# How to tell React which .env file to use?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, environment-variables

I have a React app that I run with the command:

```
npm run dev
```

This launches the app and uses the `.env.local` file.
I want to be able to configure a file called `.env.production` that will be used instead of `.env.local` when I run the command `npm run prod`.

These are my current scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**install [npmjs.com/package/env-cmd](https://npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)**

```
 "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "start:local": "env-cmd -f ./.env.local react-scripts start",
        "start:Dev": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development react-scripts start",
        "start:QA": "env-cmd -f ./.env.test react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried and got this `'env-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

Answer (score 0):

Create a new scripts key and use REACT_APP_ENV :

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod" : "REACT_APP_ENV=prod npm run dev"
  },
```